# NHibernate mapping by code using interfaces

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

Given the following class structure

```
public class OrderHeader
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<IOrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    ... 
}

public Interface IOrderDetail
{
     Guid Id { get; set; }
     ...
}

public class OrderDetail : IOrderDetail
{
     public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
     ...
}
```

The following NHibernate mapping by code file is used.

```
    public class OrderHeaderMap : ClassMapping<OrderHeader>
{
    public OrderHeaderMap()
    {
        Id(item => item.Id,
            map =>
            {
                map.Generator(Generators.Guid);
            });
        Bag(item => item.OrderDetails,
            cm =>
            {
                cm.Key(k =>
                    {
                        k.Column("IOrderDetailsId");
                        k.NotNullable(true);
                    });
                cm.Inverse(true);
                cm.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans);
                cm.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
            },
            r => 
            {
                r.OneToMany(rm =>
                    {
                    });
            });
    }

    public class IOrderDetailsMap : ClassMapping<IScrewlineExpressionBlock>
    {
        public IOrderDetailsMap()
        {
            Id(item => item.Id,
                map =>
                {
                    map.Generator(Generators.Guid);
                });
        }

        public class OrderDetailsMap : JoinedSubclassMapping<OrderDetails>
        {
            public OrderDetailsMap()
            {
                Key(k =>
                    {
                        k.Column(col =>
                            {
                                col.Name(typeof(IOrderDetails).Name + "Id");
                            });
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the IOrderDetailsId field mapping the header Id field in the details table is not being set.

The code used to write the records is

```
using (DAO dao = new DAO())
{
foreach (IScrewlineConditionExpression entry in modifiedValues)
{
    IScrewlineConditionExpression header;
    if (entry.Id.Equals(Guid.Empty) || (header = dao.GetById(entry.Id)) == null)
    {
            Guid id = dao.Create(entry);
        header = dao.GetById(id);
    }
    dao.Update(header);
}
}

...
public PK Create(T newItem)
{
    return (PK) Session.Save(newItem);
}

public T Update(T updatedItem)
{
    T result = Session.Merge(updatedItem);
    Session.Flush();
    return result;
}
```

So, should the Id of the parent record automatically be applied to the detail records on update/merge or is it something I have to do prior to the update.  I would be thinking this is a difficult proposition as there is no accessible property on the detail record to update.

What is wrong with the way I am updating, or with the way the information is mapped that is preventing the update of the ID field from occurring?

Any query is failing to find the detail records as the SQL generated relies on the IOrderDetailsId field to locate the detail records.

Comment: Why does your OrderDetail need an interface? Generally you don't put interfaces on models.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use an interface or not - somebody always wants it the other way.  So you have never had a model that needs to support different order detail information?

Comment: I have had to support different data, but I solve that by using Table Inheritance. http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/08/fluent-nhibernate-table-inheritance-discriminators-part-2/